# Invalid null pointer error when using ifstream

Tags: c++, nullpointerexception, ifstream

So I have this strange "invalid null pointer" exception in this code (cut down to the core of the problem)

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main(){
    std::ifstream input;
    std::ofstream output;

    unsigned __int16 currentWord = 0;

    output.open("log.txt");
    input.open("D:\\Work\\REC022M0007.asf", std::ios::binary);

    input.seekg(0, input.end);
    int length = input.tellg();
    input.seekg(0, input.beg);

    for (int i = 0; i < length;){
        int numData = 0;
        input.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(currentWord), sizeof(currentWord));
    }
    input.close();
    output.close();
    return 0;
}
```

The line that gets me exception is

```
input.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(currentWord), sizeof(currentWord));
```

and it do so on the very first go-through, so it's not like I was trying to read file further, than it is.

When I try to change value of `currentWord` to 1 I get exception like

```
trying to write to memory 0x0000001
```

or smth along the lines (number of zeroes may not be correct)

Web search told me it have something to do either with file being empty (which is not the case), not found (not the case either, as length gets value) or something in type casting mumbo-jumbo. Any suggestions?

Comment: Takes its address (`&currentWord`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'currentWord' is ZERO (0) and when `reinterpret_cast<char*>(currentWord)` is executed it makes it a `nullptr` so when you try to write to the null address you'll get a memory write protection error.

change it to `reinterpret_cast<char*>(&currentWord)` (note the `&`)

Comment: Oh, thank you. Pointers and all this memory manipulation was always a little tricky for me

Answer (score 1):

You are using the value of `current_word` as though it were a pointer. It isn't. That's why you get a null pointer address when `current_word` is zero and you get a memory exception at address 1 when `current_word` is 1. Use `&current_word` as the first argument to `input.read()`.